# TYPO3 7.6: bodytext html output with typoscript?

Tags: html, xml, typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

After I upgraded TYPO3 from 6.2.9 to 7.6.15 the bodytextfield isn't parsed as HTML anymore. My typoscript creates XML output and I need the bodytext as HTML output.

```
...
  10 = CONTENT
  10 {
    table = tt_content
    select {
      where = colPos=0
      orderBy = sorting
      selectFields = image,header,bodytext
      languageField = sys_language_uid
  }

  wrap = <items>|</items>


  renderObj = COA
  renderObj {

    wrap = <item>|</item>


    10 = TEXT  
    10 {
      wrap = <title>|</title>
      field=header
    }

    20 = TEXT  
    20 {
      wrap = <text><![CDATA[ | ]]></text>
      field = bodytext
      parseFunc = < lib.parseFunc_RTE
    }
...
```

I think the `lib.parseFunc_RTE` is not working anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Using =< you are referencing to lib.parseFunc_RTE. If it gets deleted somewhere in your Typoscript, the reference will be lost. Check out the Template -> Typoscript if lib.parseFunc_RTE is still present in your Typoscript.

You also can try to not reference it by just copying it

```
parseFunc < lib.parseFunc_RTE
```

Comment: I found out that lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines.nonWrappedTag > removed my p tags, no it's looking good and I will test ist